# imageStore() operation on dimensions beyond buffer size

Tags: opengl, compute-shader

I have compute shader in which I have uimage2d buffer and imageStore() operations on that buffer. I want to know what would be behaviour if i write to locations beyond the size of buffer. Would be there some wrap effect ? Or behaviour depends on driver ? Or will it undefined and anything can happen?

Answer (score 1):

According to the specification, an access to a texel which doesn't exist has no effect.

See [OpenGL 4.6 API Core Profile Specification - 8.26. TEXTURE IMAGE LOADS AND STORES](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf); page 193:

> If the individual texel identified for an image load, store, or atomic operation doesn’t exist, the access is treated as invalid. Invalid image loads will return zero.
>   **Invalid image stores will have no effect**. Invalid image atomics will not update any texture bound to the image unit and will return zero. **An access is considered invalid if:**
>
> [...]
>
> - **the selected texel doesn’t exist**

Comment: I saw that in specs but I am observing different behavior so I was curious if there is any chance based on shader compiler there is any difference.